# Seemingly incorrect string equality in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j

In my Neo4J database I have nodes with a string property called `node_type`, 99% of my 8000 or so nodes have `'node'` as their property value.

I have a Cypher query which is meant to return the 1% of nodes that don't have that property value:

```
MATCH (m:FooLabel) - [r:CHILD] -> (n:FooLabel) WHERE TRIM( m.node_type ) <> 'node'
```

This returns all of the nodes that don't have `'node'` as their property value, but it also returns about 46 nodes that **do** have `'node'` as the property value:

[image]

How do these nodes match the predicate?

Answer (score 2):

In the screenshot you are doing the string comparison on `m.node_type` but returning `n`.

Do you mean to compare `m.node_type` or `n.node_type`?

Comment: Is there a difference between `m` and `n` in this context? I note that when I do `m.node_type = 'node'` I get 8000+ results.

Comment: Yes, the difference is that `m` is the node on the outgoing side of the relationship (`r`) and `n` is the node on the incoming side of the relationship `r`. If you want exclude nodes with the `node_type` property of `node` then change your query to compare the property on both `n` and `m`: `... WHERE trim(n.node_type) <> 'node' AND trim(m.node_type) <> 'node'`